# Disable X-FrameOptions response header for a URL Spring Security JAVA config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x-frame-options

I am trying to disable or set the XFrameOptions header to SAME_ORIGIN for a particular URL in my Spring Boot project with Spring Security. I am pasting the code below,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity    
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {            
        RequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/course/embed/**");

        DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter headerWriter =
                new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(matcher,new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter());

        http.headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .addHeaderWriter(headerWriter);
    }    
}
```

I am using AntRequestMatcher but that does not work, it instead disabled the XFrameOptions header for all the responses. Is there a better way to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure multiple HttpSecurity instances. The key is to extend the WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter multiple times. For example, the following is an example of having a different configuration for URL’s that match with `**/course/embed/**`. If matches X-Frame-Options will be SAMEORIGIN, otherwise DENY.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebMVCSecurity {
    //Configure Authentication as normal, optional, showing just as a sample to indicate you can add other config like this
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    // Create an instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that contains @Order to specify which WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be considered first.
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // The http.antMatcher states that this HttpSecurity will only be applicable to URLs that match with **/course/embed/**
            http.antMatcher("**/course/embed/**").headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        }
    }

    // Create another instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. 
    // If the URL does not match with **/course/embed/** this configuration will be used. 
    // This configuration is considered after ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter since it has an @Order value after 1 (no @Order defaults to last).
    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin();

            //bla bla bla ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried with multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I get this error  " Refused to display 'https://localhost/modern/course/embed/33510' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' " when "/course/embed" is called. So the antMatcher still does not match the pattern. Am i missing something?

Comment: If your URL is /course/embed then pattern should be set as /course/embed*

Comment: sorry, I missed your full url path. try with this /**/course/embed/**

Comment: thank you shi !, this worked perfectly !! all this while i was thinking it was not a problem with the pattern.

Comment: So if there is another url to match, extending WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter is the right way to go ? just for that url.

Comment: If pattern is different for new url, just add another class extending WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter and remember to set @Order(2) for that

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to:

1. Disable the default spring security which uses a `XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter` to add X-Frame-Options to responses
2. Configure a new [HeaderWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/header/HeaderWriter.html) that only delegates to an `XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter` for the paths you actually want X-Frame-Options to be added to

Sample code:

```
public class AlignSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
      http.headers()
        .frameOptions().disable()
        .addHeaderWriter(new CustomXFrameOptionsHeaderWriter());
    }

    private static class CustomXFrameOptionsHeaderWriter implements HeaderWriter {
        private final XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter defaultHeaderWriter;
        
        private static final Set<String> ALLOWED_TO_EMBED_IN_IFRAME = ImmutableSet.of("/some/path");
    
        public CustomXFrameOptionsHeaderWriter()
        {
            this.defaultHeaderWriter = new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.DENY);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void writeHeaders(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            if (!ALLOWED_TO_EMBED_IN_IFRAME.contains(request.getRequestURI()))
            {
                defaultHeaderWriter.writeHeaders(request, response);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```